# PHP: Hash function that generates a string with a given length

Tags: php, hash

I need a function that creates a hash from an arbitrary parameter set (or a serialized string) with a fixed length (say 5), as I need these hashes to serve as keys in an external database with a limited key length (so md5 will not work).

Is there such a function? Or should I use md5 and then substring it?

Comment: A very bad idea(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a hash of a small fixed length is practically worthless, from both a security and a practicality point of view. Say you have a datablock string of 512 bytes (64 characters) length, how is that going to be hashed into a unique string of 5 characters (40 bytes)?

Say you do develop a "small" hash, it'll be something you'll have made yourself so it will be inherently insecure so you're going to all this trouble for not much return.

- Why do you need a hash at all?

  - What security risk are you trying to mitigate?
- Why are you not using more secured `password_hash` functions or similar?
- ***[Don't roll your own](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)***.

You could try and truncate your `MD5()` hash but really, it's a 32 character hash and you're cutting it down to five, that means you have a huge chance of collisions, where two source values make the same hash. This is already one of the issues of md5, and that's with 32 characters, with 5, you're trying to stop a sinking ocean liner by bailing out with a teacup.

Man the lifeboats instead.

You might as well set up a random bytes generator such as [`OpenSSL_random _pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) or [`random_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php), to give you random blocks, and then associated them with an [**Associative database table**](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=association.php).

## So a *possible* solution:

```
$bytes = random_bytes(10);
var_dump(bin2hex($bytes));
```

Their table:

> ```
>  id  | their data
> -----|-----  
>  10  |  gedgfdgfdhfd 
>  11  |  dgdgfdhfdhf  
>  15  |  dfsgdfhdffdhf
> ```

Your table:

> ```
>   id  | key | random_hash
>  ----------------------------
>    1  | 10  | 7bc4cb77c27d8b0a49eb
>    2  | 15  | a49ebc89b757bc4ccb4e
> ```

So the user knows the `random_hash` and you can equiate this to the id of the row from the external table that you need. This would take a bit of setup work and *I make a lot of assumptions about your situation* but it's a possible solution.

---

Anything you do with hashes of say 5 characters is going to not be worth the time you spend writing the code (
[Source](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-should-i-calculate-the-entropy-of-a-password) ):

[image]

Also note that this graphic is from 2010 and so now, computers are even faster and more capable of breaking your hash ( [Source](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/12/how-quickly-can-your-password-be-cracked/) ).

---

## Overall : Don't do it.

Comment: The hash I need is not for security, but to create an single identifier for an entity that is defined by 3 independent parameters, which have to be packed into a short string and still be unique. I agree, hashing is probably a wrong solution, and I decided to use hexadecimal data packing to fit them all.

Comment: Then it does't need to be a hash at all, simply concatenate the 3 identifiers and add a random 000-999 key (or similar) to the concatenation.

Comment: If you need to preserve the identity of the elements in your parameters, then hashing is entirely the wrong way of doing it. You may want encryption but it sounds more like you simply need to concatenate or to save them to a DB with a single numerical identifier to cross reference when needed

Comment: concatenation exceeds the limit. But knowing that one of the parameters does not exceed 255, and 2 others do not exceed 15, I can pack them to four character hexadecimal string safely